# Python Kivy On Screen Keyboard Focusing on Field

Tags: python-3.x, windows, keyboard, kivy, on-screen-keyboard

I am trying to make an on screen keyboard with Kivy, and I need a recommendation for how to go about it. I need to find out how to have the field that I want to type into focused, and have my Kivy window still functional. My code currently only generates the keyboard structure. Pressing on the key does nothing.

I have tried some of the `win32` libraries, but I did not understand them very well.

Now, if I select the field I want and press a button on the keyboard, the Kivy window is now in focus so the letter doesn't go to the field.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Any code would be appreciated!

Comment: What code would you like to see?

Comment: @Pokechu48: Instead of creating your own keyboard, you could use [Kivy VKeyboard](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.vkeyboard.html)

Comment: I have tried using that, but it is not what I want. I want to create an application such as the Windows On-Screen Keyboard.

Comment: @Pokechu48: Could you please provide minimal code, screen print(s), and steps to recreate the problem(s). Thank you.

Comment: What code do you want to see? Currently the code only places the buttons. When a button is clicked, it simply prints the letter of the key. I am just wondering how I can type a letter into a different application, such as a web browser